# What is the best way to build a data structure for Selenium project to test if Menu has all needed submenus and test if all menus are displayed?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, data-structures

I'm learning `Selenium` with `Java` and have an application with the top menu bar that has different menus with sub menus.

For, example, I roll mouse over Menu1 and I get Submenu1 and then when I roll mouse over a Submenu1 I get Submenu2.

So, the hierarchy looks like that:

```
MENU_1
SubMenu1_Item1
SubMenu1_Item2
    SubMenu2_Item1
    Submenu2_Item2
SubMenu1_Item3
    SubMenu3_Item1
    Submenu3_Item2
    Submenu3_Item3
```

What is the best way to create a data structure in Java to test if Menus have correct sub menus?

I was thinking about creating different `enum` types or create a Dictionary where key is sub menus name and a value is menu names:

```
Dictionary mainMenu = new Hashtable();
mainMenu.put("SubMenu1_Item1", "MENU_1"); 
mainMenu.put("SubMenu1_Item2", "MENU_1"); 
mainMenu.put("SubMenu1_Item3", "MENU_1");
```

So, I can do the same for all the menus and then get all the menu items with `findElements()` for a particular menu and compare counts or search for the missing menu

What is the best way to do all that?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Enum along with Map (HashMap or Hashtable) shall be one of the best way to create data structure specifically to scenario you mentioned. You can create Enum like below and store associated sub menu details using hashmap and can get later on to validate.

```
public enum Menu1 {
    SUBMENU_Key_1,
    SUBMENU_Key_2,
    SUBMENU_Key_3,
    SUBMENU_Key_4,
    SUBMENU_Key_5;
}

Map<String, Object> subMenuContext = new HashMap<String, Object>();
subMenuContext.put(Menu1.SUBMENU_Key_1,"SUBMENU1_Value");
subMenuContext.put(Menu1.SUBMENU_Key_2,"SUBMENU2_Value");
subMenuContext.put(Menu1.SUBMENU_Key_3,"SUBMENU3_Value");
subMenuContext.put(Menu1.SUBMENU_Key_4,"SUBMENU4_Value");
subMenuContext.put(Menu1.SUBMENU_Key_5,"SUBMENU5_Value");
```

Hope, this helped you.